# Arrow style over the text using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply an arrow style on selected ul, li elements.

[image]

However, I am quite sure how to do that.
So far I am able to do this
[image]

below is my code.

```css
.appText,
.prodText {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.appText.selected,
.prodText.selected {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .075);
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: applications()">
                            <li data-bind="click: values())">
                                <div class="appText" data-bind="css: { selected: val}">
                                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                                </div>
                                <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
                                    <li data-bind="click: values()">
                                        <div class="prodText ProdText" data-bind="css: { selected: val">
                                            <span class="prodName" data-bind="text: name, attr: { title: name }"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Do you also need the horizontal arrow on the right?

Comment: What is a "selected" list item? You should really simplify this post by removing all the irrelevant templating attributes, etc. All you really need is a bit of HTML and CSS. You can dump a solution into your app code later. See [ask].

Comment: your snippet is not helping, nothing shows. You can try something alike: `div {text-indent:1em;border:solid lightgreen; width:max-content;min-width:10em;margin:2px;border-radius:0.3em 1em 1em 0.3em;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0.5em) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0.5em) 100%, 0 100%);  background:linear-gradient(to left, lightgreen, lightgreen 1em, transparent 2em)}` or inspire yourself from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYzPJyK (made for another question here)